# WAS8.5 vs WAS 7 JPA performance issues

Tags: websphere-8

We have same ear that installs fine and works on both WAS 8.5 and WAS 7.0. With how it is coded it connect to multiple  domains such as cert, train and mock domains or separate one for prod. It uses subject figure out what domain to connect too. The problem is 1st transcation to a domain was little slower on WAS 7.0 close to 5- 6 secs, but now on WAS 8.5 it takes somewhere around 10 - 25 seconds not sure what is going on.

More testing on the end on WAS 8.5, all the request headers need authentication, client always sends with authentication header, We were thinking it JPA, but we saw 1st request that comes to server takes good 10 - 25 secs respond. After that all the  other requests are relatively faster. When monitored the WAS 8.5 we see almost 1 core constantly consumed by the Java process. Plus constantly pinging the ODR which keeps the CPU for that process to be high

Just wondering anybody has similar problem on this upgrade, where they are initial call to JPA is being comparatively slower to WAS 7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation we found websphere was scanning jars resource annonations and this happens on 1st request. There is configuration on websphere that will make sure this scanning doesn't happen. If that is setup correctly it works as expected.

The property is document as such like this

com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.SkipMetaInfResourcesProcessing = true

we got this from http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Frweb_jsp_staticfile.html